# Entity Framwork 5: Why is my entity's collection property empty?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm currently learning the Entity Framework (EF) through the Code First approach. I want to model a simple one-to-many relationship between `Professor`s and `Class`es on a newly created database (i.e. created by the EF).

In my model a `Professor` has a collection of `Class`es. A `Class` always has one `Professor` associated with it (i.e. the corresponding property is never null). I can create and store a `Class` and an associated `Professor`, but when I access the `Classes` property of a `Professor` retrieved from the database, it is empty. Navigating from a `Class` to its `Professor`, however, is possible.

Consider the following model:

```
class Class
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual Professor Professor { get; set; }
}

class Professor
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private ICollection<Class> classes = null;

    public virtual ICollection<Class> Classes
    {
        get { return classes ?? (classes = new HashSet<Class>()); }
        set { classes = value; }
    }
}

class ClassManager : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Professor> Professors { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Class> Classes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Class>().HasRequired(c => c.Professor);
    }
}
```

In my main method I create and access my data like so:

```
    using (ClassManager db = new ClassManager())
    {
        Professor p = new Professor() { Name = "McTest" };
        Class c = new Class() { Title = "Testing Tests", Professor = p };

        p.Classes.Add(c);

        db.Professors.Add(p);
        db.Classes.Add(c);

        Console.WriteLine(db.SaveChanges() + " change(s) saved.");
    }

    using (ClassManager db = new ClassManager())
    {
        foreach (Professor p in db.Professors)
            Console.WriteLine("Prof. " + p.Name + " gives " + p.Classes.Count 
                + " classes.");

        foreach (Class c in db.Classes)
            Console.WriteLine(c.Title + " (Prof. " + c.Professor.Name + ")");
    }
```

The output is:

```
3 change(s) saved.
Prof. McTest gives 0 classes.
Testing Tests (Prof. McTest)
```

The generated DB schema is:

```
table Classes
    column Id (PK, int, not null)
    column Title (nvchar(max), null)
    column Professor_Id (FK, int, not null)
table Professors
    column Id (PK, int, not null)
    column Name (nvchar(max), null)
```

As you can see, the `Classes` collection property does not appear anywhere in the schema. Is that intended?

Can someone please shed some light into this? All the examples I've found wouldn't go into detail about collection properties.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, after hours of searching I found the solution. It seems like one has to instruct the EF explicitly to load the collection properties of an entity when querying the database:

```
foreach (Professor p in db.Professors.Include("Classes"))
    Console.WriteLine("Prof. " + p.Name + " gives " + p.Classes.Count
        + " classes.");
```

The `Include` method does that.

Comment: I already upvoted you in the past probably years ago, but ran into this again recently and your Q&A here were the first place I found a working answer. (I also found the problem in MSDN but as usual for recent MSDN, not really in a form that led me to a clearly useful syntax.) Sometimes I can't believe how weird MS SQL framework designs are. I also can't believe this question is only at +1 votes and is not so easy to find. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> The two separated using statements in my main code are intentional. If I merge them together, the Classes property suddenly is not empty, but I don't understand why.

If the 2 are merged into 1 then you "query" the local entities that are stored in-memory, not the database.

in your first context you do not need to add both `professor` and `class` to the context. just add the professor and the `class` will be saved too.

check the DB schema and make sure the entities are properly mapped to the database.

finally, change the `Professor` class to

```
class Professor
{
    public Professor()
    {
         Classes = new List<Class>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Class> Classes {get; set;}
}
```

I suspect the lazy loading is being trumped by the is null logic to return a hashed set.

Comment: I applied your suggested changes, but the outcome is the same. I also updated my question with a description of the DB schema. Please take a look, if you find any anomalies there.